# vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders always undefined - vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I can't figure out why vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders is always defined. When I hit F5 to launch window to test extension, I initially saved the file in a folder and if I restart F5, the file is still in that folder so it's technically in a workspace, but when I run my extension, I get from the following code:

> workspace folder is undefined

What am I doing wrong that is causing me to not get my workspace folder? I appreciate any help!

```ts
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('my-app.helloWorld', () => {

        let folderOutput;
        if (vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders) {
            folderOutput = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.fsPath;
            vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`workspace folder: ${folderOutput}`)
        }
        else {
            vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`workspace folder is ${vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders}`)
        }
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

export function deactivate() { }
```

Comment: if there is no Folder open in the VSC instance, `vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders` is `undefined`, you can have files open

Comment: When I hit F5 it originally opens an untitled/unsaved file. What I did was save as and created a folder and put that file in the folder. Whenever I hit F5 now, it always goes to that file in the folder so wouldn't that work or am I missing something?

Comment: use **File** > **Open Folder** in the launched instance and call your command

Comment: When you do file > open folder, it opens a new instance of vscode. When I hit ctrl + shift + p and search for my extension to launch, it doesn't come up in that instance. Only the debug window instance has the extension when I search for it. How can I open folder, but in the instance with the extension app so I can run it?

Comment: if `file > open folder` gives a new instance there is something really bad with your VSC install, close all VSC instances, use task manager and delete all VSC instances/processes remaining, restart VSC

Comment: When I say new instance, I mean a new vscode window with that folder I just opened folder on, which doesn't have my extension listed. Not sure if there's a difference.

Comment: I've also tried doing ```code -r .``` which I think opens it in the same window. And I went to preferences > window > new window and set ```Open Folders In New Window``` to off so it always opens in same window as debugger, but I still get undefined

Comment: Copy your extension to the extension folder of VSC, no need to start a debugger, close all VSC and start VSC, What does `Open Folder` now do, What foes happen when you have a Multi Root Workspace.

Comment: That seemed to output the workspace folder, thanks!. I tried ```vsce package``` earlier and then installed the extension in vscode to try the same thing, but I got undefined. Today I tried it your way and deleted what I installed before and copied the app extension folder directly to .vscode > extensions folder and it worked.

Comment: compare the two ways of installing, are the directories different